# Weighted K-means for my super market vs K-means

Tags: python, r, k-means

I have a Super Market. I want to find if product A is out of stock which product should i replace with. I am not sure what should i do, someone suggested me K-means for that. If sppose my data looks like

[image]

I would like understand what should i handle these categorical values(red, yellow, sweet sour, veg etc).
I can convert then into values but that would be random and scale them at the end so now we will get rid of dominant features. What if i start giving weights. to these categories of an attribute based on total sales by color, total sales by type veg or non veg. And if i give weights to values what would be its impact.

Comment: You could create dummy variables for each of the categorical variables or alternately, perform factor analysis and then use the resulting principal components as input to your kmeans

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the right place to ask about choosing a statistical method since that's not really a specific programming question. This question has been asked and answered already on a more appropriate site: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data